# Undefined $variable by creating dependent dropdown bookable activity

Tags: php, sql, laravel

**Project**: bookable activity 
**Error**: Undefined variable $days 
**Description**: creating mini-eshop which you can choose if you want to go for riding, doing arts or do guided tour. User have to choose 3 of the activities by choosing time and day which are inserted manually at database managment.
**More error details**: at https://flareapp.io/share/Bm0jQD07#F47
**Update**: According to your ideas  i take off getDates() and use the getIndex() by doing that

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $products = Product::all(); 
        $days = DB::table('days')->pluck("day","id");
        return view('shop.index',compact('days'), ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

and found the variable $days but not times.

web.php

```
//use db;

Route::get('product.index','ProductController@getDates');
Route::get('product.index/gettimes/{id}','ProductController@getTimes');
```

productcontroller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function getDates()
    {
        $days = DB::table('days')->pluck("day","id");
        return view('shop.index',compact('days'));
    }

    public function getTimes($id) 
    {
        $times = DB::table("times")->where("time_id",$id)->pluck("time","dayoftime","id");
        return json_encode($times);
    }

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);


        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }

    public function getCart()
    {
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return view('shop.shopping-cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        return view('shop.shopping-cart', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
    }

    public function getCheckout()
    {
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return view('shop.shopping-cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $total = $cart->totalPrice;
        
        return view('shop.checkout', ['total' => $total]);
    }

   

    public function getReduceByOne($id){
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->reduceByOne($id);
        if (count($cart->items) > 0){
            Session::put('cart', $cart);
        } else{
            Session::forget('cart');
        } 
        return redirect()->route('product.shoppingCart');
    }

    public function getRemoveItem($id){
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->removeItem($id);
        if (count($cart->items) > 0){
            Session::put('cart', $cart);
        } else{
            Session::forget('cart');
        }       
        return redirect()->route('product.shoppingCart');
    }
    public function postCheckout(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return redirect()->route('shop.shoppingCart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_ptSt4XL8KRmHvbdVAsvC7bAk00EOC00h7u');

            // Token is created using Stripe Checkout or Elements!
            // Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
                if ( isset($_POST['stripeToken']) ){
                    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
                }
            try {
                $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                    'amount' => $cart->totalPrice * 100,                    
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'description' => Carbon::now().' '.$request->input('card-name'),
                    'source' => "tok_mastercard",
                ]); 
                

                $request->validate([
                    'cardname' => 'max:35',
                    'name' => 'max:12',
                    'surname' => 'max:13',
                ]);
    
                $order = new Order();
                $order->cart = serialize($cart);                
                $order->cardname = $request->input('cardname'); 
                $order->name = $request->input('name'); 
                $order->surname = $request->input('surname');                
                $order->payment_id = $charge->id;
               
                Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);

            } catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message1', 'Your payment was declined.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message2', 'To many requests to the API.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message3', 'Invalid parameters.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message4', 'There are problems with authentication.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message5', 'There is a problem with the network.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message6', 'There is a problem with the API.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $request->session()->flash('fail-message7', 'We don\'t know what happened.');
                return redirect()->route('checkout');
            }       
            Mail::send('shop.order_confirmation', [
                'user' => Auth()->user(),
                'products' => $cart->items,
                'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice,
            ], function($message) use ($user) {
                    $message->to($user->email);
                    $message->from("@@@gmail.com");
                    $message->subject("Your order confirmation");
                    $message->bcc("@@@gmail.com");
                }
            );         
        Session::forget('cart');
        return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('success', 'Successfully purchased products! | You will receive an oder confirmation at your email');
    }    
}

migration days

    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('days', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('day');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

migration times

    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('times_id');
                $table->string('dayoftime');
                $table->string('time');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

index.blade.php else shop.index

```
    section('title')
    Shopping Cart
@endsection
@section('content')    
    @foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productsChunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($productsChunk as $products)
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{ $products->imagePath }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>{{ $products->title }}</h3>
                            <p class="description">{{ $products->description }}</p>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                jQuery(document).ready(function ()
                                {
                                        jQuery('select[day="day"]').on('change',function(){
                                        var dayID = jQuery(this).val();
                                        if(dayID)
                                        {
                                            jQuery.ajax({
                                                url : 'shop.index/getdates/' +dayId,
                                                type : "GET",
                                                dataType : "json",
                                                success:function(data)
                                                {
                                                    console.log(data);
                                                    jQuery('select[day="day"]').empty();
                                                    jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                                                    $('select[day="day"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $('select[day="day"]').empty();
                                        }
                                        });
                                });
                                </script> 
                                <div class="container">                            <
                             <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="days">Select Day:</label>
                            <select day="day" class="form-control" style="width:250px">
                                <option value="">--- Select Day ---</option>
                                @foreach ($days as $key => $value)
                                <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="time">Select Time:</label>
                            <select time="time" class="form-control"style="width:250px">
                            <option>--Time--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery(document).ready(function ()
                            {
                                    jQuery('select[time="time"]').on('change',function(){
                                    var times_id = jQuery(this).val();
                                    if(timesID)
                                    {
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            url : 'index/getindex/' +timesId,
                                            type : "GET",
                                            dataType : "json",
                                            success:function(data)
                                            {
                                                console.log(data);
                                                jQuery('select[time="time"]').empty();
                                                jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                                                $('select[time="time"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $('select[time="time"]').empty();
                                    }
                                    });
                            });
                </script>                  
                                <div class="pull-left price">${{ $products->price }}</div>
                                <a href="{{ route('product.addToCart', ['id' => $products->id]) }}"
                                   class="btn btn-success pull-right" role="button">Add to cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: The error you're getting should provide more detail, such as the line number of the file that is throwing the error. Providing greater error detail would be very helpful considering the quantity of code (a lot of which seems irrelevant) you've provided. However, having a _guess_, it would be your `index.blade.php` throwing the error with the `@foreach($days as $day)` as your `postCheckout` function doesn't include it anywhere when it redirects.

Comment: @Peppermintology fo more details shared it at https://flareapp.io/share/Bm0jQD07#F47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking at the code for Controller...

You are calling *getDates* method of *ProductsController* which opens the index.blade.php inside shops folder in resources...

```
public function getDates() // shop.index needs both $products and $days
{
    $days = DB::table('days')->pluck("day","id");
    return view('shop.index',compact('days')); // No Products sent.. 
}
```

**Index** has *$product* ... so when u open the index page from *getDates* method it wont have the $products variable...

```
public function getIndex() // shop.index needs both $products and $days
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]); // no Days sent.
}
```

Both the variables **$days** and **$products** are needed in the shop.index template in shops folder.

secondly, opening a route that would call the **index** method of the *ProductController* would open the shop.index template but won't find the *$days* variable as it is not being sent in the Index function of *ProductsController*.

Comment: You mean @Anand changing to: Route::get('shop.index','ProductController@getIndex');
Route::get('shop.index/gettimes/{id}','ProductController@getIndex'); and public function getIndex()
    {
        $products = Product::all(); 
        $days = DB::table('days')->pluck("day","id");
        return view('shop.index',compact('days'), ['products' => $products]);
    }

Comment: @RubenOchoa you can pass both variables in the same compact function...  public function getIndex() { $products = Product::all(); $days = DB::table('days')->pluck("day","id"); return view('shop.index',compact('days', '$products')); }

Comment: cannot be passed both cause error says that: "compact(): Undefined variable $$products" @Anand

Comment: Sorry @RubenOchoa my bad inside compact("days", "products"); not $products.... That was my bad sorry...

Comment: No need to say sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So the stack trace provided by you at https://flareapp.io/share/Bm0jQD07#F47 shows that your error is occurring on line 24 of your `ProductController` and is due to you trying to use a variable `$days` which you’ve neither declared nor initialised:

```
return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products], ['days' => $days]);
```

You need to declare and initialise the `$days` variable to resolve the error.

For example:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $days = Day::all();
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products, 'days' => $days]);
}
```

Comment: update my post. So you can see what i did.